# How to guess number of required WAVEHDR Array/Buffer in Wave audio recording

Tags: visual-c++, buffer, audio-recording, waveform, audiobuffer

i want to write a audio recording program using win32 WAVE API and then stream it.
but i want to know how i can guess the number of WAVEHDR buffer for recording audio?

```
WAVEHDR mInputDeviceBuffer[NUM];
```

the value of NUM is needed.
does it selected based on special formula or it is completely chosen by developer neeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming audio is a real time operation, and Windows is not a real time operating system. The amount of buffering needed to bridge this gap is the amount of audio data that could come in while your program is not executing due to multitasking. How long does your program have to wait under Windows if some other operation is started while you are recording? Maybe 1-1.5 seconds.

So the answer to how many buffers you need depends on the audio data rate, and the size you choose for the buffers, then make enough of them to cover a worst-case suspension time that my tests indicate could be as much as 1.5 seconds.